# where to include Checkbox & make editable

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using ajax to call my web service & displaying the Json value in Table data. Now the client wants to make the data editable in each row thereby clicking the check box.

Once the check box is clicked the row should be editable. pls help me where to include the check box in the below code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: "http://localhost:8080/karthi/", // Location of the service
    success: function (json) {//On Successfull service call

    var txtStr = '<table class="datatable"><thead><tr> <th>id</th> <th>firstName</th> <th>lastName</th> <th>licenseId</th> <th>telephone</th> <th>email</th> </tr></thead><tbody>';

    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

     txtStr += '<tr class="gradeA"> <td><a class="edit_row" href="#tab2" onclick="showDetails(\''+json[i].id+'\');">'+json[i].id+'</a></td> <td>'+json[i].firstName+'</td> <td>'+json[i].lastName+'</td> <td>'+json[i].licenseId+'</td> <td>'+json[i].telephone+'</td> <td>'+json[i].email+'</td> </tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Include it inside showDetails().
Have it as the first column right before id field.
Have a new heading for checkbox inside thead tag

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I have added the heading inside the thead, but i need the check box in each row. So that the user can click the check box & make the row editable

Comment: @Karthick88it Have radio buttons as: 'code' <input type="radio" name="chkBox1" value="row1" onClick="javascript: yourfn()"> 'code' Have this code inside showDetails(). Looks like your code create rows inside this function